# can't connect to postgres after restarting mac PG::ConnectionBad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, homebrew, postgresql-9.2

It's been a long time since I restarted my mac, and now that I have restarted it, my rails apps will no longer connect to postgres.

PG::ConnectionBad

The problem is, i can't remember how i installed postgres, I'm not sure if i used homebrew or not... I know it was a later version of postgres as I am using Hstore.

**Is there any way to tell or find which version I WAS using, and start the server?**

--

**I found 9.2**

/usr/local/var/PG_VERSION = content of file says 9.2

/usr/local/var/global = has a lot of numbered files. I am guessing these are my databases?

**I also found 9.2.2**

/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.2 but i cant find data files.

Comment: Run the command `brew list` to see what packages you have installed, then run `brew info postgres` to for detail on the package

Comment: Ah. i did this before... but didnt read the bottom of the notes. i just ran **pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start** and now im back in business

Comment: Cool, do you want to answer your own question then?  Or you want me to answer it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command `brew list` to see what packages you have installed, then run `brew info postgres` for detail on the package...

That should tell you what you need to do, and (as you found out) run command:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```